# Hide div inside list item if another div is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I have several `<div>` elements of different classes within each `<li>` element. If one of them having a `testsimonial-content` class is empty, how can I hide another `div` of class `testsimonial-heading` within the same `<li>` as well? It shouldn't affect other `<li>`s.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="testsimonial-heading">Testimonial</div>
        <div class="testsimonial-content">Hello this is a testimonial</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="testsimonial-heading">Testimonial</div> <!--This div should be hidden-->
        <div class="testsimonial-content"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="testsimonial-heading">Testimonial</div>
        <div class="testsimonial-content">Hello this is a testimonial</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry I actually have more than 2 divs within each li, can you make it hide the class .testimonial-heading?

What would be the updated javascript for this? Instead of hiding parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".testsimonial-content:empty").parent().hide(); 
    // if content is empty - then hide
});
```

or this one if you need to hide `li` if **any** of `div`s is empty

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".testsimonial-content:empty, .testsimonial-heading:empty").parent().hide(); 
    // if content OR heading is empty - then hide
});
```

Here is the [working JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q1pewqwr/).

**Update from the OP:**

> Sorry I actually have more than 2 divs within each li, can you make it hide the class .testimonial-heading? What would be the updated javascript for this? Instead of hiding parent.

Here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".testsimonial-content:empty").siblings(".testsimonial-heading").hide(); 
    // if content is empty - then hide heading in this li only
});
```

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q1pewqwr/2/).

Comment: Sorry I actually have more than 2 divs within each li, can you make it hide the class .testimonial-heading?

What would be the updated javascript for this? Instead of hiding parent.

Comment: @KimTran Check this out.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#ul li').each(function() {
  var div = $(this).find('.testsimonial-content');
  console.log(div.text().length);
  if (div.text().length === 0) {

    div.siblings('.testsimonial-heading').hide();

  }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='ul'>
  <li>
    <div class="testsimonial-heading">Testimonial</div>
    <div class="testsimonial-content">Hello this is a testimonial</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="testsimonial-heading">Testimonial1232131</div>
    <!--This div should be hidden-->
    <div class="testsimonial-content"></div>
    <div class="testsimonial-">Other div</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="testsimonial-heading">Testimonial</div>
    <div class="testsimonial-content">Hello this is a testimonial</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Find the class `testsimonial-content` using `.find()` get its length using `.length` and if zero hide its sibling using `.siblings().hide()`

Comment: Sorry I actually have more than 2 divs within each li, can you make it hide the class .testimonial-heading?

What would be the updated javascript for this? Instead of hiding parent.

Comment: @KimTran add the class of the sibling you want to hide.